# psql asks for password and does not read from pgpass.conf

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have installed my Postgresql database on a Windows server environment. I'd like to schedule a job using **Windows Task scheduler** to run every night so I need to run the following command without asking for password:

```
psql -U myUserName-d myDBName -c "select MyFunctionName()"
```

When I run the above query in my `cmd` shell, it asks me for password. When I enter the password manually, the function is correctly run.

So my solution is to read from the `pgpass.conf` file so no password is required.

Here are the things I have done to achieve this:

I created the `pgpass.conf` file in a directory I created in the `%appdata%` (`AppData\Roaming\postgresql` to be precise).

Here are the contents of this file:

```
localhost:5432:myDBName:myUserName:myPassword
```

I have also tried with the value `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` above.

I, then, added the an environment variable (in the *user variables for administrator* list) called `PGPASSFILE` and gave it the `pgpass.conf` location.

```
;C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

Finally I stopped and restarted my Postgres service on Windows services and re-ran the command. But it is still asking for password.

How can I let my command know from where to read the password?

Comment: The `;` at the start of the filename looks wrong

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried both with and without it. But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: did you try to `SET PGPASSFILE` in cmd prompt first?..

Comment: @VaoTsun this did the trick. what was i missing? if you have the explanation please write it as an answer.

Comment: no, no - I did not run Postgres on windows since early 2000. it was just a wild guess - if you can't set environment variables via gui - try on command prompt. Alas - answer would require windows knowledge, not postgres, thus won't be mine

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable, put the password file in the standard location `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` as described by [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: And that is what I had done. But it didn't work. That's why I added the `SET PGPASSFILE=[PATH_TO_pgpass.conf]` in the bash script but I wanted it to read automatically from env vars.

Comment: Your questions sounded like it were somewhere else. Do you get the right file when you open a DOS box and run `TYPE %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`?

Comment: In addition I would like to say that the actual path on Windows10 is `'AppData\Roaming\postgresql'` even if you typed in Win+R `'%APPDATA%\postgresql\'`.